# What is the cost of i18n in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, internationalization

In flex, most of the i18nized string are injected through the binding with `{resourceManager.getString()}`.
Practically, it generates dozen of listener waiting for an update of the resourceManager.localeChain that will rarely (or never in most of the cases...) happen.

I am wondering what is the actual cost of databinding, if there is a way to limit this overhead and if framework such as babel fx are useful?

Note: in my business, this is not an issue if when the user changes its locale he has to logout/login to the the updated labels.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an example a few months ago how to get rid of data binding easily, if it should become an issue.

From my point of view, it is not the data binding is not all that bad, but when having a lot of resource strings this might lead to a few moments of unresponsiveness. If babel is a better option, i can't tell. You will have listeners being invoked when the locale changes and i think my solution ([L18nExample@github](https://github.com/floriansalihovic/L18nExample)) is fine in terms of performance. A way to optimize would be implementing setter, which correspond properly to the components live cycle.

Comment: Thanks. What you are doing in your project is more or less what has been implemented by babel fx. Do you have an idea of what number of label is hidden behind _a lot of resource strings_?

Comment: No sorry, i haven't used babel in the past.